# For data driven test using robotframework, is it possible to have more than one data driver (using more than one datasheet)?

Tags: python-3.x, automation, robotframework, data-driven-tests

I'm currently doing a data-driven test. I created a test template that will use data from one excel file(specific sheet) for the input data. Is it possible that I import the data from more than one excel sheet in a single robot file?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. Use for loop to search through several files one by one.
you can use something like below: f1,f2,f3 etc.

`with open(filepath, 'r') as f1:

lines = f.readlines()

for line in lines:

#do something`

Comment: is robot framework capable of doing this?

Comment: Yes, you can add a python code as a Library to your settings area. Call that function in robot using Run/Start Process  pythonprogname 
more details at - https://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/Process.html#Run%20Process

Comment: so you are suggesting using python script instead of data driver in robotframework for this? My test cases are in a test template.

Comment: basically what I want is that i import a xlsx file with several datasheets, I want different test case use data from different datasheets

Comment: @WongChungsze Hi you got any solution for this?

Comment: @ThomasNT unfortunately no

Comment: @WongChungsze - It is answered in more detailed in this post - https://stackoverflow.com/a/44686289/17663093

Comment: One more alternative - https://forum.robotframework.org/t/read-and-parse-excel-data/937/13 - it is a great discussion on using a https://rpaframework.org/libraries/excel_files/ library.